# If $F$ is equicontinuous at each closed neighborhood, then $F$ is equicontinuous at compact set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I want to prove following

> Let $D$ be open commected subset of $\mathbb{R}$. If $F$ is family of $f : D \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ that is equicontinuous on each closed disk $ \vert z - z_{0} \vert \leq r $, then $F$ is equicontinuous on each compact set $K \subset D$

Since $K$ is compact, I can write $ K = \cup_{i=1}^{n} N(z_{i}, \delta_{i}) $ where $F$ is equicontinuous on closure of $N(z_{i}, \delta_{i})$.

My attempt was letting $\delta = \min \delta_{i}$. But even if $ \vert z - z' \vert < \delta$, $z$ and $z'$ may be contained in different $N(z_{i},\delta_{i})$, so I can't go further.

How can I get desired conclusion?

Comment: Each compact set is contained in a disk of a sufficiently large radius.

Comment: Sorry. I edit my post. Domain was not $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, just open connected set $D$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Suppose the conclusion fails. Then we get $\epsilon >0$ and sequences $(x_n), (f_n)$ with $|f_n(x_n)-f_n(y_n)| \geq \epsilon$ for all $n$ with $x_n -y_n\to 0$. There is a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ converging to some $x$. Note that  $(y_{n_k})$ also conveges to the same limit $x$. Now apply the hypothesis to a neighbohood of $x$ to get a  contradiction.